# qmake -project command gives QFileInfo warning in Qt 4.6

Tags: qt, qmake

I've upgraded to Qt 4.6 on my Mac (OS 10.5).

When I go to a project directory and run:

`qmake -project`

Qt returns this warning (although it doesn't say it's a warning, I assume it is since the .pro file gets created anyway):

```
QFileInfo::absolutePath: Constructed with empty filename
```

I did a completely new install thinking that the "upgrade" wasn't clean for whatever reason, it still does it.

Any ideas as to why?

Here is an example .pro that results from above command:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Mon Apr 19 07:39:53 2010
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = 
DEPENDPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
RESOURCES += jquery.qrc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known [bug](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-7176). Will be fixed Qt 4.6.3.

Comment: Haha, just found out :). Thanks.

So that just means that qmake creates a QFileInfo with an empty string then calls absolutePath(), right?

Comment: Yes. Somewhere in qmake sources there is undefined behavior due to that fact. =)